# 'no module named <site>' Flask, Gunicorn, Nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

My site has been running more or less fine for ~1.5 years. I occasionally experience an intermittent power outage which requires me to restart nginx and gunicorn. About 1.5 months ago my server was out of space which similarly required me to clear some space and also reboot nginx/gunicorn.

In each case I was faced with a 502 Bad Gateway error, but rebooting nginx/gunicorn solved the problem.

Yet again, I am faced with a 502 Bad Gateway error but restarting the server does not work. Instead, I get the following issue when running the command below:

```
/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5001 --worker-class socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker sonification:app
```

There are no changes to my server configuration. Everything has worked in the past! I don't even know the first step to debugging something like this. Any pointers?

```
user@site:/var/www/sonification/sonification$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)user@site:/var/www/sonification/sonification$ pip freeze
/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.4.1
Flask-SocketIO==0.6.0
gevent==1.0.2
gevent-socketio==0.3.6
gevent-websocket==0.9.3
greenlet==0.4.7
gunicorn==18.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
uWSGI==2.0.10
Werkzeug==0.10.4
wheel==0.24.0
(venv)user@site:/var/www/sonification/sonification$ gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5002 --worker-class socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker sonification:app
2017-06-28 14:59:45 [23115] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2017-06-28 14:59:45 [23115] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5002 (23115)
2017-06-28 14:59:45 [23115] [INFO] Using worker: socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker
2017-06-28 14:59:45 [23120] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23120
2017-06-28 14:59:45 [23120] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named sonification
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named sonification
2017-06-28 14:59:45 [23120] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23120)
2017-06-28 14:59:45 [23115] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2017-06-28 14:59:45 [23115] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Have also tried:

```
  user@site:/var/cache$ /var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5001 --worker-class socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker sonification:app
    2017-06-25 16:51:12 [6352] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
    2017-06-25 16:51:12 [6352] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5001 (6352)
    2017-06-25 16:51:12 [6352] [INFO] Using worker: socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker
    2017-06-25 16:51:12 [6357] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6357
    2017-06-25 16:51:12 [6357] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
        worker.init_process()
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
        self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
        self.callable = self.load()
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
        return self.load_wsgiapp()
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
        return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
        __import__(module)
    ImportError: No module named sonification
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
        worker.init_process()
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
        self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
        self.callable = self.load()
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
        return self.load_wsgiapp()
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
        return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
      File "/var/www/sonification/sonification/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
        __import__(module)
    ImportError: No module named sonification
    2017-06-25 16:51:12 [6357] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6357)
    2017-06-25 16:51:12 [6352] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2017-06-25 16:51:12 [6352] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: Have you activated the virualenv  before starting gunicorn?

Comment: good thought, but yes I've also tried running gunicorn when my virtual environment is activated via gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5002 --worker-class socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker sonification:app and I still receive the "No module named <app>" error :/

Comment: I added the output from running in my virtual environment, as well as a list of installed dependencies